# How to loop through all but the last item of a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Using a `for` loop, how can I loop through all except the last item in a list? I would like to loop through a list checking each item against the one following it. Can I do this without using indices?

Answer (score 431, accepted):

```
for x in y[:-1]
```

If `y` is a generator, then the above will not work.

Comment: That answers my question, thanks, but I forgot to ask how I would get the item after x. Is this possible?

Comment: I believe an "else" statement will allow you to handle what happens after the loop just don't forget to set x to the last element.

Comment: - 1
I don't think that answer the question. It is not comparing each item with the next one. – odwl 0 secs ago

Comment: I think I did. Author said he would like to do X, then asked how he can do Y. I answered how he can do Y. 

That he accepted my answer would indicate I answered the question he asked, if not the question he _really_ wanted to ask.

Asker is welcome to demote this answer.

Comment: Just because the OP should have asked another question in the first, does not mean that his question and this answer are not very useful to others. +1

Comment: I don't know what everyone else is talking about - this answers question quite well and is very, very efficient classic Python code! kudos!

Comment: I think after (considerable) hindsight some grief and a few downvotes was worth it in the end :)

Comment: You mention that this does not work for generators. What's the alternative when `y` is a generator?

Comment: Doesnt this create a new list? Seems wasteful.

Comment: @Sush Why would it create a new list? Seems like a dumb interpreter.

Answer (score 61):

the easiest way to compare the sequence item with the following:

```
for i, j in zip(a, a[1:]):
     # compare i (the current) to j (the following)
```

Comment: Actually, you can omit the first slice, since zip truncates the longer list to the length of the shorter. This will save you one list creation.

(Just in case you are dealing with huge lists. But in that case, you should follow Ants Aasma's approach, which does not copy anything.)

Answer (score 23):

If you want to get all the elements in the sequence pair wise, use this approach (the pairwise function is from the examples in the itertools module).

```
from itertools import tee, izip, chain

def pairwise(seq):
    a,b = tee(seq)
    b.next()
    return izip(a,b)

for current_item, next_item in pairwise(y):
    if compare(current_item, next_item):
        # do what you have to do
```

If you need to compare the last value to some special value, chain that value to the end

```
for current, next_item in pairwise(chain(y, [None])):
```

Comment: please note, that use of next for variable name shadows built-in

Comment: I personally don't mind shadowing less used builtins when the scope of the variable is small and the name is good for readability. Nevertheless edited the variable names to maintain good coding practices.

Answer (score 8):

if you meant comparing nth item with n+1 th item in the list you could also do with

```
>>> for i in range(len(list[:-1])):
...     print list[i]>list[i+1]
```

note there is no hard coding going on there. This should be ok unless you feel otherwise.

Comment: You could replace len(list[:-1]) with len(list) - 1 to avoid a list copy. And avoid using a variable called list...

Answer (score 2):

To compare each item with the next one in an iterator without instantiating a list:

```
import itertools
it = (x for x in range(10))
data1, data2 = itertools.tee(it)
data2.next()
for a, b in itertools.izip(data1, data2):
  print a, b
```

Comment: that's exactly what was suggested by Ants Aasma http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914715/python-looping-through-all-but-the-last-item-of-a-list/914786#914786

Answer (score 2):

This answers what the OP *should have asked*, i.e. traverse a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) comparing consecutive elements (excellent [SilentGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914815/341320) answer), yet generalized for any group (*n-gram*): 2, 3, ... `n`:

`zip(*(seq[start:] for start in range(0, n)))`

Examples:

```py
seq = range(0, 4)  # list(seq) -> [0, 1, 2, 3]

list(zip(*(seq[start:] for start in range(0, 2)))) # == [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
list(zip(*(seq[start:] for start in range(0, 3)))) # == [(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
list(zip(*(seq[start:] for start in range(0, 4)))) # == [(0, 1, 2, 3)]
list(zip(*(seq[start:] for start in range(0, 5)))) # == []
```

Explanations:

- `seq[start:]` returns (slices) a sequence starting from index `start`
- `*seq`: unpacks all the sequence's (or iterable's) elements to the enclosing function `zip`, as if it was written `zip(elem1, elem2, ...)`

Note:

This code is lazy except for the slicing.

Comment: this doesn't work for generators, did you possibly confuse `range` for a generator (it's not)

Comment: @CervEd you were right, thank you! I re-documented it accordingly.