# How should I grab pairs from a list in python?

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list that looks like this:

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8', 'item9', 'item10']
```

Using Python, how would I grab pairs from it, where each item is included in a pair with both the item before and after it?

```
['item1', 'item2']
['item2', 'item3']
['item3', 'item4']
['item4', 'item5']
['item5', 'item6']
['item6', 'item7']
['item7', 'item8']
['item8', 'item9']
['item9', 'item10']
```

Seems like something i could hack together, but I'm wondering if someone has an elegant solution they've used before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Looping through all but the last item of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914715/python-looping-through-all-but-the-last-item-of-a-list)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A quick and simple way of doing it would be something like:

```
a = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8', 'item9', 'item10']

print zip(a, a[1:])
```

Which will produce the following:

```
[('item1', 'item2'), ('item2', 'item3'), ('item3', 'item4'), ('item4', 'item5'), ('item5', 'item6'), ('item6', 'item7'), ('item7', 'item8'), ('item8', 'item9'), ('item9', 'item10')]
```

Comment: Even more compact than the list comprehension. I've never even seen zip before.

Comment: Very nice. I didn't realize that zip would effectively reduce down the list like that.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the `pairwise` recipe in the [`itertools` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
[(foo[i], foo[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(foo) - 1)]
```

Comment: Indeed it does, bravo! I knew there was something I could do with a list comprehension, but just wasn't sure how to approach it. Thanks!

Comment: this produces tuples not lists as the OP asked for

Comment: The OP actually only asked for pairs, but if you would prefer a list over a tuple, you just change to `[foo[i], foo[i+1]]` in the comprehension.

Comment: what about foo[i:i+1]? I'd think that may be faster.

Comment: That doesn't actually work because [a:b] indexes from a to b-1, which only results in one number. This does work:

[foo[i:i+2] for x in xrange(len(foo) - 1)]