# How can I replace the vowels at the end of a word by other letters?

Tags: python, function, str-replace

This is my solution so far:

```
def chemificateWord(word):

vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y','A','E','I','O','U','Y')

word2 = []

for letter in word:

    if not word.endswith(vowels):
        word2 = word + 'ium'
    return word2
```

''' So when I now `print(chemificateWord(Californ))`

The result I want is:

```
Californ**ium**
```

So I want to replace to last ending letters if they are vowels with 'ium', could anyone help? '''

Comment: Here's a hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914715/how-to-loop-through-all-but-the-last-item-of-a-list

Comment: This kind of removal is exactly what `.rstrip` does. There are tons of people who accidentally use it wrongly and don't want it to work the way that it does; this is the rare exception that is the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def chemificateWord(word):    
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y','A','E','I','O','U','Y')

    word2 = word

    while word2.endswith(vowels):
        word2 = word2[:-1]
    word2 += "ium"
    return word2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
Additional, if I would like to replace all ending vowels by 'ium'? So in this case this would be replacing 'ia' by 'ium'. (and even if there are more ending vowels than 2)

Comment: @RobinVdc see the new solution

Answer (score 1):

You might use `re` module for this task following way:

```
import re
def chemicate(word):
    return re.sub(r'[aeriouyAEIOUY]*$', 'ium', word)
```

Then:

```
print(chemicate('Californ'))  # Californium
print(chemicate('Baaa'))  # Bium
```

First argument of `re.sub` is so-called pattern, `[]` denotes any of characters inside (vowels in this case), `*` denotes 0 or more repeats, `$` is zero-length assertion and denotes end of string.